# converter extension in c++

Tags: c++, fstream

I was trying to create a program using the lib fstream to take all lines of one documents like main.cpp or main.docx and convert that to a file with .txt, like copy and paste. However, I'm having trouble within my class.

ps: I'm a beginner

the problem in my compiler is in de checker more specifically is at the method documents checker in the 'newdocument.ope()...'

```
#ifndef CONVERTER_H_
#define CONVERTER_H_
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <vector>




class DocumentCreator{
    public: 
        std::string line;
        std::string extension; 
        std::string DocumentName; 
        std::fstream document, newdocument;
        void listDocuments();
       void  DocumentChecker();


};

void DocumentCreator::DocumentChecker(){

        DocumentName=DocumentName+".txt";
      

        newdocument.open((DocumentName), std::ios::in | std::ios::app);
        document.open(DocumentName+extension, std::ios::in | std::ios::app);
        if(document.is_open()){
            if(newdocument.is_open()){ 
                while(getline(document,line)){
                    newdocument<<line<<std::endl;
                    } }}        
}

void DocumentCreator::listDocuments(){
    system("ls");
}

#endif
```

and my main code:

````
#include <iostream> 
#include "converter.h"


using namespace std; 


int main(){

    bool in_out;
    
    DocumentCreator *dc1;


    system("clear"); 
    cout<<"*********************************";
    cout<<"\n*                               *";
    cout<<"\n*                               *";
    cout<<"\n*           CONVERTER           *";
    cout<<"\n*                               *";
    cout<<"\n*                               *";
    cout<<"\n*********************************\n\n";
    
    system("ls");
    
    cout<<"\n\nIs your document in this list TYPE 0 or 1: \n\n-1 YES \n-0 NO\n: ";
    cin>>in_out; 
    
    system("clear");
    
    if(in_out==true){

        system("clear"); 
        system("ls");
        cout<<"TYPE YOUR DOCUMENT NAME: ";
        cin>>dc1->DocumentName; 

        cout<<"\nTYPE YOUR DOCUMENT EXTENSION\nEX: .pdf .c .txt\n: ";
        cin>>dc1->extension;

        dc1->DocumentChecker();
        

         

    }

     




    return 0; 
}```
````

Comment: .cpp and .docx are very very different formats. You appear to aim to support only plain text formats based on the provided code; things like docx pretty much require specialized libraries and then you have to define what counts as a line with everything that could possibly go into a docx.

Comment: Be kind to people, format you code to make it a beauty. Why so much empty lines?

Comment: "I'm having trouble within my class." Can you elaborate? What sort of trouble?

Comment: FYI, you also haven't initialized your pointer. If your compiler isn't warning about that, you need warnings turned up.

Comment: `newdocument.open((DocumentName), std::ios::in | std::ios::app);` Shouldn't it be opened for output instead of input.

Comment: Note: as a beginner, there's no way you're going to be ready to read PDF or word document files. Those are complex formats that require entire libraries to parse.

Comment: If you want to only change the extension, look at `std::rename`.

Comment: About the pointer, the compiler wasn't warning, I could do with rename. Though I've searched about read a document is a thing hard as I'm still a beginner. And sorry guys about the lack of information about the code, was my first time "reporting" a problem. Btw thanks everyone.